# Primusrun/Optirun allegedly cannot locate/open config directory: "/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg

I have recently switched from open source drivers to nvidia, to bumblebee as instructed by ubuntuforums.org users to better use my two gpu's capabilities.
It also so happens that it does not seem to work at all, I keep getting this error regardless of which command I try.

Doing ll /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d I can see that this presumed config file is a directory, I am not too knowledgeable about this but I think it's correct provided the .d extension.

Full error:

```
optirun glxgears
[ 9546.928811] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) Unable to locate/open config directory: "/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d"
```

```
primusrun glxgears
primus: fatal: Bumblebee daemon reported: error: [XORG] (EE) Unable to locate/open config directory: "/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d"
```

EDIT:
I didn't specify it but yes `xorg.conf.d` exists and if I try use ll on that directory my result is this:

```
ll /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 jan  2 14:54 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 jun 18 22:55 ../
```